# Database errors in Mirth channel

Tags: mirth

I want to use Mirth to connect to a database, then write a record to a table in that database.

The record contains a field "file_name", and this file name contain `Date` value, so a new file whose name would be like this:

```
temp_2015-08-10
```

This is what I passed to Mirth Destination SQL field:

```
INSERT INTO statutory_reports (str_est_id, str_type, str_create_date, str_created, str_record_status, str_file_path, str_file_name, str_created_by) VALUES (2, 'temp', CURDATE(), NOW(),'approved', 'C:/application/reports/temp reports/gumcad/', 'temp'+ ${date.get('yyyy-M-d hh:MM:ss')}, 'SHEP');
```

The problem is I get an error:

```
Database Writer error
ERROR MESSAGE: Failed to write to database
com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseDispatcherException: Failed to write to database
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseDispatcherQuery.send(DatabaseDispatcherQuery.java:143)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseDispatcher.send(DatabaseDispatcher.java:103)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.DestinationConnector.handleSend(DestinationConnector.java:738)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.DestinationConnector.process(DestinationConnector.java:436)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.DestinationChain.call(DestinationChain.java:155)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.Channel.process(Channel.java:1656)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.Channel.dispatchRawMessage(Channel.java:1155)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.SourceConnector.dispatchRawMessage(SourceConnector.java:191)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.SourceConnector.dispatchRawMessage(SourceConnector.java:169)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseReceiver.processRecord(DatabaseReceiver.java:200)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseReceiver.processResultSet(DatabaseReceiver.java:160)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseReceiver.poll(DatabaseReceiver.java:117)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.PollConnector$PollConnectorTask.run(PollConnector.java:131)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2015-8-10 09:08:44'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2758)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2826)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1302)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseDispatcherQuery.send(DatabaseDispatcherQuery.java:130)
```

Comment: It looks like data would be truncated, check the length of the column and compare it with length of actual data you want to insert.

Comment: please select the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the database is expecting yyyy-MM-dd for a DATE and you are providing yyyy-M-dd hh:mm:ss (note the month with one digit).

Format your date correctly with two digit month and remove the time part. If you want to provide the time, your database type should be DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty descriptive: `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2015-8-10 09:08:44'`

The value (a date) is not of type double.

`str_create_date` or `str_created` is defined as double in your DB, but you are writing a Date type to it, which does not match.

If this is not the case, can you copy your DB schema here for validation?

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't due to security reason. But I'm the one create the DB schema, its datatype is DATE, I think the problem is from the API or something else.

Answer (score 0):

vim to /opt/mirthconnect/conf/mirth.properties

under the database url copy this : **jdbc:mysql://localhost/mirthdb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC**

The new JavaMysql odbc seem to have this as a requirement, I think for security reasins